# Asp.Net Application Architecture With Sencha Ext JS 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, extjs4

I look that nice documentation about Ext JS 4 applciation architecture. It tells clearly an architecture which contains only one html page, others js.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/docs/index.html#!/guide/application_architecture

If i want to use this library with Asp.Net Mvc, how should my architecture like?

**EDIT:** I mean that there is a mvc architecture in Ext Js, another one in Asp.net. How to combine these two architecture?

Comment: Erm, like it explains in that documentation... Or can you be more specific in your question?

Comment: @Amalea I mean that there is a mvc architecture in Ext Js, another one in Asp.net. How to combine these two architecture?

Comment: In that case, I think it's a subjective question and not really suited for stack overflow as it's kinda "what suits you best".

Comment: May be. or kinda "best practise". but i think there are many question like that. should i delete this question?

Comment: You can check how [Dextop](http://dextop.codaxy.com/showcase) is doing that...

Comment: it looks good @Marko . Can you write this comment as an answer that i can accept it?

Comment: I have posted my answer and added more stuff you should check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check how [Dextop](http://dextop.codaxy.com/showcase) is doing that. You should also check [this demo app](http://dextop.codaxy.com/pecunia). Source code is available on the [GitHub](https://github.com/codaxy/dextop-pecunia).

Answer (score 0):

In my use of EXT JS and ASP.net MVC together, I would use the ASP model and controllers for EXT JS Direct calls from a few pages in the ASP view layer. There is also new single page application that I am wanting to look into in MVC 4 that may make this even easier.